# Install error on Vite project with Svelte

Tags: node.js, npm, svelte, vite

I want to try out svelte, but whenever I try to install all the npm dependencies it just won't work.

Here's the latest log from the `npm install` command:

```
358 verbose stack Error: command failed
358 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:63:27)
358 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
358 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
358 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
359 verbose pkgid esbuild@0.14.54
360 verbose cwd C:\Users\[name]\Documents\svelte\svelteproject
361 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
362 verbose node v16.17.0
363 verbose npm  v8.15.0
364 error code 1
365 error path C:\Users\[name]\Documents\svelte\svelteproject\node_modules\esbuild
366 error command failed
367 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Temp\postinstall-348afd82.cmd
368 error node:internal/errors:477
368 error     ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
368 error     ^
368 error
368 error <ref *1> Error: spawnSync node ENOENT
368 error     at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1112:20)
368 error     at spawnSync (node:child_process:827:24)
368 error     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:870:15)
368 error     at validateBinaryVersion (C:\Users\[name]\Documents\svelte\svelteproject\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:89:32)
368 error     at C:\Users\[name]\Documents\svelte\svelteproject\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:240:5 {
368 error   errno: -4058,
368 error   code: 'ENOENT',
368 error   syscall: 'spawnSync node',
368 error   path: 'node',
368 error   spawnargs: [
368 error     'C:\\Users\\[name]\\Documents\\svelte\\svelteproject\\node_modules\\esbuild\\bin\\esbuild',
368 error     '--version'
368 error   ],
368 error   error: [Circular *1],
368 error   status: null,
368 error   signal: null,
368 error   output: null,
368 error   pid: 0,
368 error   stdout: null,
368 error   stderr: null
368 error }
369 verbose exit 1
370 timing npm Completed in 8482ms
371 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1662249334912
372 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1662249342838
373 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1662249342839
374 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1662249342839
375 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1662249342853
376 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/esbuild 1662249342854
377 verbose code 1
378 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
378 error     C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-03T23_55_34_708Z-debug-0.log
```

I created the project by running `npm init vite` and followed all the steps. The only issue arose when I ran the `npm install` command in the root directory of the project.

Comment: You might have a older version of create-vite installed, try to create your project with `npm init vite@latest`